# Use regular category with custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm using WooCommerce that uses a custum post type (`product`) with its own product category taxonomy (`product_cat`). Now I'm using an other plugin (minimu) that selects posts to display based on the normal WordPress category. Seeing as my custom post types don't belong to a regular category it displays nothing... Now I want to make it so that I can assign a product category as well as a normal category to each post.

How would I have to modify this? I guess adding something to the custom post declaration of WooCommerce? But no idea how and what?

**EDIT**

Found this code, that makes it able to assign regular categories to custom post types but now my importer doesn't assign them, but I think I'll be able to fix this.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse6098_init', 100 ); // 100 so the post type has been registered
function wpse6098_init()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'product' );
}
```

This post may be deleted, tried to do it myself

Comment: Please always link to any used plugin, theme, repo, etc. Thanks.

Comment: And please move your edit to an answer. This is a system that saves solutions for later users.

Answer (score 2):

Found this code, that makes it able to assign regular categories to custom types but now my importer doesnt assign them, but I think ill be able to fix this.

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse6098_init', 100 ); // 100 so the post type has been registered
function wpse6098_init()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'product' );
}
```